# Costmap 2D Kinect/Laser clearing problem when encountering objects with thin legs (e.g. tables or chairs)

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, costmap, laserscanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have noticed a conceptual problem while navigating with a static, forward facing Kinect in combination with a 270degrees laserscanner. When I encounter a table with thin legs, the Kinect will put the top of the table as a pointcloud in the costmap. This way, my robot will successfully replan a path around the table instead of through it. HOWEVER, when my robot turns to go around the table, my LASERSCANNER will clear the top of the table again, hence allowing a replan through the table again! With this my robot seems to get in a deadlock situation when encountering a table (or anything with thin legs). I do need both sensors to 'mark' and to 'clear' obstacles. Is there any way I can circumvent this problem with the current implementation (i.e. by using just the .yaml configuration files for move_base), or do I really need to make a whole new implementation for this? My solution would be to have each sensor ONLY clear their own obstacles, and NOT the ones detected by the other sensor. But this doesn't seem possible with the current implementation. Any ideas would be --> very welcome!!

Thanks!!

Rob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32633/costmap-2d-kinect/laser-clearing-problem-when-encountering-objects-with-thin-legs-(e.g.-tables-or-chairs)/) by [Rob Janssen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2252/rob-janssen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Dariush, currently we are using an octomap to combine our measurements. However, back then we've also tried setting the map_type to 'voxel'. This didn't solve our problem then. However, maybe we should have investigated more, as indeed, setting the map_type to 'voxel' should be the solution.

---

Originally posted by [Rob Janssen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2252/rob-janssen/) with karma: 96 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0